# Listing all files in a unix directory/sub-directory

Tags: python, unix, python-2.7, file-io, stat

I have created the following python script to list all files and their sizes present in directoris/sub-directories

**Code A**

```
files = glob.glob("%s/*.*"%os.getcwd())

sorted_file = sorted(files, key=os.path.getsize)

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    for d in dirs:
        for f in glob.iglob(os.path.join(path, d, '*.*')):
            print f ,os.path.getsize(f)
```

I am getting the following error when it runs trhough the directories:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 27, in <module>
    print f ,os.path.getsize(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/genericpath.py", line 49, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/My/Folder/Perlx.x'
```

Strangely when I go to the `/My/Folder/` in unix box and do a `ls -l` , I can see `Perlx.x` whihc it truns out is a `Symbolic Link`

**Code B**

```
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    for name in files:
        f = os.path.join(path, name)
        print f,os.path.getsize(f)
```

Error :

```
/My/Folder/BEA
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 19, in <module>
    print f,os.path.getsize(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/genericpath.py", line 49, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/My/Folder/BEA'
```

In both cases BEA and Perlx.x are `Symbolic Links` which exits in the specified folder. How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: why do you think you need to call `glob.igob`. The `walk` command will yield all the directories and files under `os.getcwd()`

Comment: Also, don't use `glob.glob(".../*.*")`; it is faster and cleaner to use `os.listdir` on the target directory instead.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. Could it be that there is some other process moving files around?

Comment: Mate , nothing is moving the files around. When I access the same through UNIX , I can view the files.

Comment: I have the same problem in linux but only with links to non-existing files.

Comment: In my case the file do exist , which is why I am finding it strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of the error , I put in an extra condition which checks if the file is link or not.

```
   for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(choicedir):
        for name in files:
            f = os.path.join(path, name)
            if not os.path.islink(f):
                modified = os.path.getmtime(f)
                size = float(os.path.getsize(f))
```